# Rename [android-pay] tag to [google-wallet]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Currently, the [android-pay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-pay) tag has the synonym [google-wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-wallet), but now Google has officially changed the name from Android Pay to Google Wallet. [You can see here that the new name is Google Wallet.](https://developers.google.com/wallet)

Can a mod please flip it so that the tag is [google-wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-wallet) with the synonym [android-pay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-pay)?

I realize it gets a little confusing because the [Android Pay](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/) link that's on the tag description redirects to Google Pay, even though the description is clearly about the digital wallet component. This is because GPay and Wallet also used to be the same product, but have since split into two separate things.

Asking here on meta because is a bit of an edge case to swap a tag with its existing synonym.

Comment: [Better source for the change itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Wallet#Google_Pay_becomes_Google_Wallet_(2022)) (seeing as the page you linked also says "Google Pay" in a couple places). It was called Google Wallet, then it became Google Pay, and now it's back to being Google Wallet, [because Google](https://killedbygoogle.com/)?

Comment: That wikipedia article is actually inaccurate. The long story is... it was Google Wallet (which included Google Pay), then it was Android Pay (which included Google Wallet and Google Pay), then it was GPay (which included Wallet), then Gpay and Google Wallet were made into separate things (but GPay relies on Wallet for storing cards, which is why the site I linked mentions GPay in a few places), which is where we are today =)

Comment: This one is a pretty clear article on the confusing set of apps: https://www.cnet.com/tech/mobile/google-pay-vs-google-wallet-whats-the-difference/

Comment: Any chance we can get this rename implemented? =)

Answer (score 3):

After [confirming via chat that I correctly understand the distinctions between the current and past names for Google payment services](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56788007#56788007), I've switched the direction of these synonyms, so that [google-wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-wallet) is the primary tag:

[image: screenshot of the synonyms table, showing that google-wallet is the target tag]

Currently, this isn't showing up as working yet, but that's sort of expected; the tag system has a good bit of caching.  Hopefully it should resolve itself soon; if not, someone please ping me.

Comment: So...the synonym is up, but a bug that we've hit before is preventing search from actually finding any of the old questions with the tag...  I'll try to get that written up and reviewed at some point.